# Submit a simple form using ajax and rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, controller

Im trying do build a form using ajax.

I read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html) tutorial, but it is not clear to me.

I would like to submit a simple form and show the result in the same page without refresh a page. I do not have models in my application. I just wanna submit a form, make a request to a api and show the result back to the page.

If I use this for example:

```
<form method="post" action="/my_controller/my_action" class="button_to" data-remote="true" data-type="json">
  <input type="text" ..>
  <input type="text" ..>
  <div><input value="Show" type="submit" /></div>
</form>
```

How can I get this values in my_controller and how can I show back to the view?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form

```
<form method="post" action="/my_controller/my_action" class="button_to" data-remote="true"       data-type="script">
  <input type="text" name="value1">
  <input type="text" name="value1">
  <div><input value="Show" type="submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Your display div tag

```
<div id="feeds"></div>
```

Your action

```
def my_action
   @value1 = params[:value1]
   @value1 = params[:value2]
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js
   end       
end
```

Your view my/my_action.js.erb

```
$('#feeds').prepend("<%= j ("<p>#{@value1}-#{@value2}</p>") %>");
```

Comment: The last part doesn't work for me. I have tried to put `alert("test")` and nothing. =/

Answer (score 0):

use the ajax method of jquery

```
$.ajax({
 url:'/path/to/controller',     
 type:'GET',
 data:{formData:$('form').serialize()},
 success:function(data){
 //do what ever with the response
 }

});
```

additionally you can attach an error event handler

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to edit the answer of @MuhammetDILEK, which almost worked for me.
However, I needed to use `data-type="script"` instead of `data-type="json"` in the form, as explained in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15115551/3472491