# Why I need add "data: {type: "script"}" on remote link with rails / ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ujs

in one project of mine, the code:

```
  = link_to "add", new_me_category_path, class: "btn btn-success", remote: true
```

can load remote form correctly.

But some one can not work, browser did not execute the responese js code.  I need to add  "data: {type: "script"}" like this :

```
  = link_to "add", new_me_category_path, class: "btn btn-success", remote: true, data: {type: "script"}
```

I want to know the reason.

Comment: Can you add a little more code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not JS expert, and I dont know Ruby, but i think:

When datatype is set to `script` - downloaded code is loaded and executed immediately.

When datatype is default (`html`) - downloaded code is just loaded into browser. You have to execute it "manually" (by calling some function for example).

If your code has just some functions for use with previously loaded code - these functions will be available and will work (when data type is `html`).

If there are defined events in your code - they will not work because they are not initialized, becuase code was not executed.

If my explanation is bad - you may read about difference between `jQuery.get()` and `jQuery.getScript()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes, jQuery's `ajax` method is used: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ by uJS https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs whenever the `data-remote="true"` attribute of the link is set, which is done by `remote: true`.

As stated in the documentation, Ajax determines the HTTP Accepts header sent and interprets the return value based on the `dataType` and `accepts` arguments passed to `ajax()`, which here are taken from the `data-` attributes of the anchor by uJS.

If no `dataType` is set through the `data-type` attribute, jQuery inferences the request and response type "intelligently". This can explain inconsistencies if you do not explicitly specify it.

Answer (score 1):

If you loading script correct template should have `.ejs` extension (or render raw script like this: `render js: 'some code'`). You must escape html using `j` in ejs template like this:

template.ejs

```
$('some selector').html('<%= j render('some template') %>');
```

Please give me also url. Correct one should end with `.js`.