# How do I render my JS erb?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `save_video` action on my `NodesController` that does this:

```
format.html { redirect_to video_tag_users_path(@video) }
```

What I want to happen is when it calls that action, it should render my `tag_users.js.erb`, but it is not.

This is my `tag_users` action:

```
  def tag_users
    authorize! :read, @family_tree
    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
    @node = @video.node

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end

    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

This is the log of what is happening:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/videos/164/tag_users
Completed 302 Found in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 12.3ms)


Started GET "/videos/164/tag_users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-20 08:24:09 -0500
Processing by VideosController#tag_users as HTML
  Parameters: {"video_id"=>"164"}
# truncated for brevity
  Rendered videos/tag_users.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
```

This is the file I want it to render:  `tag_users.js.erb`

```
$("#add-video-step-3").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'videos/tag_users_in_video') %>");
```

Which then renders this modal `_tag_users_in_video.html.erb`:

```
<div class="bootstrap-styles" id="add-video-step-5"> 
 <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="titles clearfix">
          <h2>Tag Users</h2>
          <p><i>Step 3 of 3</i></p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="content">
            <div>Tag someone</div>
            <%= simple_form_for @node, url: add_tagged_user_node_path(@node), method: :post do |f| %>
              <%= f.error_notification %>

              <div class="form-inputs">
                    <%= f.association :user, label: "Users", collection: @users, as: :check_boxes, checked: @node.user_tags %>
              </div>                            

              <div class="form-actions">
                <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success ladda-button" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit 1**

So I changed the `respond_to` block in my `tag_users` action to this:

```
render 'tag_users.js'
```

But now it is actually rendering the JS rather than executing it and rendering the modal I want it to render.

i.e. this is what shows up in my browser, it redirects to URL `localhost/videos/167/tag_users.js`:

```
$("#add-video-step-3").html("<div class=\"bootstrap-styles\" id=\"add-video-step-5\"> \n <div class=\"modal-header\">\n      <div class=\"titles clearfix\">\n          <h2>Tag Users<\/h2>\n          <p><i>Step 3 of 3<\/i><\/p>\n      <\/div>\n  <\/div>\n  <div class=\"modal-body\">\n    <div class=\"content\">\n           <div>Tag someone<\/div>\n           <form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"/nodes/40/add_tagged_user\" class=\"simple_form edit_node\" id=\"edit_node_40\" method=\"post\" novalidate=\"novalidate\"><div style=\"display:none\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"Jj8CsHGzcNJJuJn9HGWjNaSjIfSJaZ8N81vmZ+Zp6KQ=\" /><\/div>\n             \n                            \n            <div class=\"form-inputs\">\n                 <div class=\"control-group check_boxes optional node_user\"><label class=\"check_boxes optional control-label\">Users<\/label><div class=\"controls\"><label class=\"checkbox\"><input class=\"check_boxes optional\" id=\"node_user_id_true\" name=\"node[user_id][]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" />Yes<\/label><label class=\"checkbox\"><input class=\"check_boxes optional\" id=\"node_user_id_false\" name=\"node[user_id][]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"false\" />No<\/label><input name=\"node[user_id][]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"\" /><\/div><\/div>\n            <\/div>                           \n\n              <div class=\"form-actions\">\n                <input class=\"btn btn btn-success ladda-button\" name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update Node\" />\n              <\/div>\n<\/form>    <\/div>\n  <\/div>\n  <div class=\"modal-footer\">\n  <\/div>\n<\/div>");
```

That basically means that it is not rendering the HTML like I expect it to, but just spitting out the HTML from the view `_tag_users_in_video.html.erb` partial.

What I want to happen is for it to pop-up a modal that looks like the modal with `id=add-video-step-3`, but with the content I specified in `_tag_users_in_video.html.erb`.

**Edit 2**

The server log for the above action is:

```
Started GET "/videos/168/tag_users.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-20 10:03:56 -0500
Processing by VideosController#tag_users as JS
  Parameters: {"video_id"=>"168"}
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 57  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 57]]
   (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 57]]
  Membership Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = 57 AND "memberships"."family_tree_id" = 57
  Video Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos"  WHERE "videos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 168]]
  Node Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."media_id" = $1 AND "nodes"."media_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["media_id", 168], ["media_type", "Video"]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."context" = 'user_tags'  [["taggable_id", 41], ["taggable_type", "Node"]]
  Rendered videos/_tag_users_in_video.html.erb (23.6ms)
  Rendered videos/tag_users.js.erb (25.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 196ms (Views: 23.1ms | ActiveRecord: 84.6ms)
```

**Edit 3**

So I added the JS render to the format.html inside my `save_video` action like you suggest. This is the code:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    if @node
      format.html { render 'tag_users.js' }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

This is what the result looks like:

[image: Rendered JS]

Whereas I am trying to get it to look like this:

[image: Original Modal I am trying to get it to look like]

**Edit 4**

This is the `save_video` method in my controller (I left commented out code to see what has been tried with no success):

```
  def save_video
    authorize! :read, @family_tree
    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
    if params[:status].to_i == 200
      @video.update_attributes(:yt_video_id => params[:id].to_s, :is_complete => true)
      @node = current_user.nodes.create!(family_tree: @family_tree, media: @video, name: @video.title, circa: @video.circa)    

      if @node
        render 'tag_users.js'
      end

      # respond_to do |format|
      #   if @node
      #     format.html {  }
      #     format.js
      #   end
      # end

    else
      Video.delete_video(@video)
    end

    # respond_to do |format|
    #   format.html { redirect_to video_tag_users_path(@video, @node) }
    #   format.js
    # end

    # redirect_to root_path
    # redirect_to video_tag_users_path(@video, @node)
  end
```

Here is the server log for this permutation of the `save_video` action:

```
Started GET "/videos/172/save_video?status=200&id=bMaCxSIbJYU" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-20 13:39:19 -0500
Processing by VideosController#save_video as HTML
  Parameters: {"status"=>"200", "id"=>"bMaCxSIbJYU", "video_id"=>"172"}
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 57  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 57]]
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 57]]
  Membership Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = 57 AND "memberships"."family_tree_id" = 57
  Video Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos"  WHERE "videos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 172]]
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "videos" SET "is_complete" = $1, "updated_at" = $2, "yt_video_id" = $3 WHERE "videos"."id" = 172  [["is_complete", "t"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-20 18:39:19.959122"], ["yt_video_id", "bMaCxSIbJYU"]]
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (5.4ms)  INSERT INTO "nodes" ("created_at", "family_tree_id", "media_id", "media_type", "name", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-03-20 18:39:19.967237"], ["family_tree_id", 57], ["media_id", 172], ["media_type", "Video"], ["name", "Outro 10PP"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-20 18:39:19.967237"], ["user_id", 57]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."context" = 'user_tags'  [["taggable_id", 45], ["taggable_type", "Node"]]
  Rendered videos/_tag_users_in_video.html.erb (10.3ms)
  Rendered videos/tag_users.js.erb (12.7ms)
```

**Edit 5**

There is no front-end part that sends request to `save_video`. What happens is, the user fills out the form that appears in this modal:

```
<div id="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="popup" id="add-video-step-4" data-step="4" data-intro="GETS TO UPLOADING">
  <div class="titles clearfix">
      <h2>Upload a Video</h2>
      <p><i>Step 1 of 3</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <% if @family_tree %>
      <%= simple_form_for([@family_tree, @video], :remote => true) do |f| %>
        <div class="column">
              <div class="f-row">
                  <%= f.input :title, label: "Title:" %>
              </div>
              <div class="f-row">
                  <%= f.input :description,label: "Description:" %>
              </div>
              <div class="f-row">
                  <%= f.input :circa, as: :datepicker, start_year: Date.today.year - 5, label: "Circa:" %>
              </div>
              <div class="f-row">
                  <label for="family">Family in this video:</label>
                  <%= f.collection_select :user_ids, @family_tree.members.order(:first_name), :id, :first_name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
              </div>
          </div>
          <%= f.button :submit, "Add Video", id: "video-submit" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div> <!-- //content -->
</div> <!-- //popup -->
```

That modal then sends the request to this `Create` action in my `Video` controller:

```
  def create
    authorize! :read, @family_tree
    @video = Video.new(video_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.save
        format.html { redirect_to video_upload_path(@video) }
        # format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @video }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Which, if successful, then sends the request to this `Video#Upload` action:

```
  def upload
    authorize! :read, @family_tree

    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
    @upload_info = Video.token_form(@video, video_save_video_url(@video))

    respond_to do |format|
        ## Note that I have been tinkering with this, but it doesn't work properly yet
        format.html { redirect_to video_tag_users_path(@video, @node) } 
        format.js
    end
  end
```

Which first sends to the `video_save` in the assignment statement.

Hope that provides clarity.

**Edit 6**

This is the contents of my `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require best_in_place
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place.purr
//= require bootstrap.file-input
//= require chosen.jquery
//= require main.js
//= require spin.min
//= require ladda.min
//= require masonry.js
//= require introjs
//= require pnotify

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("input.datepicker").datepicker();
      /* Activating Best In Place && Include Success Highlighting & Bounce for comments & videos */
        $(".best_in_place").best_in_place().bind("ajax:success", function () {$(this).closest('p, h5').effect('highlight').effect("bounce", { times:3 },  { duration:400}).dequeue(); });
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();       
      $('#unread-notification').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).data('read-url');
        $.ajax({
          type: "PUT",
          url: url
        });
      });   
});
```

**Edit 7**

Here is the server log after the first `create` is called:

```
Started POST "/family_trees/57/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-23 15:05:46 -0500
Processing by VideosController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "video"=>{"title"=>"Hello There", "description"=>"This is an interesting video", "circa"=>"", "user_ids"=>[""]}, "commit"=>"Add Video", "family_tree_id"=>"57"}
  User Load (15.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 57  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (5.6ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 57]]
  FamilyTree Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 57]]
   (2.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 57]]
  Membership Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = 57 AND "memberships"."family_tree_id" = 57
   (2.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (6.1ms)  INSERT INTO "videos" ("created_at", "description", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-03-23 20:05:46.637067"], ["description", "This is an interesting video"], ["title", "Hello There"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-23 20:05:46.637067"]]
   (2.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/videos/177/upload
Completed 302 Found in 84ms (ActiveRecord: 39.2ms)


Started GET "/videos/177/upload" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-23 15:05:46 -0500
Processing by VideosController#upload as JS
  Parameters: {"video_id"=>"177"}
  User Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 57  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 57]]
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 57]]
  Membership Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = 57 AND "memberships"."family_tree_id" = 57
  Video Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos"  WHERE "videos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 177]]
  Rendered videos/_upload_video.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered videos/upload.js.erb (7.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 344ms (Views: 23.7ms | ActiveRecord: 10.3ms)
```

**Edit 8**

`_upload_video.html.erb`

```
<div class="bootstrap-styles" id="add-video-step-3"> 
 <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="titles clearfix">
          <h2>Upload a Video</h2>
          <p><i>Step 2 of 3</i></p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="content">
      <%= form_tag @upload_info[:url], :multipart => true do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :token, @upload_info[:token] %>
        <div class="uploader clearfix">
                        <%= file_field_tag :file, title: 'SELECT FILE TO UPLOAD', class: "upload" %>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success ladda-button" data-color="green" data-style="expand-left"><span class="ladda-label">Upload Video</span><span class="ladda-spinner"></span></button>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

`upload.js.erb`

```
$("#add-video-step-4").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'videos/upload_video') %>");
```

Comment: You have a `respond_to` section which redirect your response to `render.html`

Comment: So should I remove the `format.html` from that block?

Comment: replace it with render `render 'tag_users.js'`

Comment: the whole respond_to I mean

Comment: or redirect to that action with `video_tag_users_path(@video, format: :js)`

Comment: @lx00st I updated the question with the results of what I was trying. I get the same result (i.e. the page being rendered rather than the modal being executed.) when I do it the `format: :js` way.

Comment: try my previous comment with `video_tag_users_path(@video, format: :js)` with your respond_to section

Comment: @lx00st Yep it does the same thing. I updated the question again with more info. Refresh. The good news is we are getting close.

Comment: By the way, I am not sure if it is outputting the JS like that, because I added this to my controller: `protect_from_forgery except: :tag_users`. Could that be the reason? I had to add that because that `escape_javascript` line kept throwing a security warning about InvalidCrossOriginRequest. It would be awesome if I could figure out how to fire my modal and not have to invalidate CrossOrigin checks.

Comment: have you tested `localhost/videos/167/tag_users.js` with your original `respond_to` section?

Comment: I just did and it gave me the same output as above.

Comment: and what is server log when you do this?

Comment: Updated the question with the server log. It seems legit, it is just that it is not actually swapping out the HTML content like I would assume. But just printing the escaped HTML to the screen....whereas I want it to render the modal that was just on the screen and just swap out the content with the new content.

Comment: It starts to look messy but if you want to `save_video` and then just render js you should render js directly in 'save_video' method (instead of redirecting somewhere) but if you really want to redirect - than you can render your modal without any javascript (directly inside your views)

Comment: So here is what is happening, I have 3 modals. This one I am rendering is the last of the 3. The video upload process all takes place in modals. So what should happen is once you get through step 2/3 (i.e. that modal), you should transition to this last modal at 3/3. But everything I did to get step 2/3 working, is not working for step 3/3 and I can't figure out why.

Comment: if you want to save video and render popup than you should do what i said - render your js inside `save_video` action instead of redirecting

Comment: I tried that, see updated question with the results. Should I just do a str8 `render 'tag_users.js'` outside of the format block? If so, should I leave the format block?

Comment: I also tried doing just `render 'tag_users.js'` in `save_video` and it is giving me the same escaped JS (i.e. it is just displaying the raw code and not the rendered HTML version).

Comment: can you show the `save_video` method and server log when its called?

Comment: @lx00st Done. Refresh question.

Comment: @marcamillion please include frontend  part which send request.

Comment: use `render js: 'tag_users.js'`

Comment: and show your front-end part which sends request to save_video

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar and @lx00st I have added the code that sends request to `save_video`. Note though, that it isn't any front-end code.

Comment: @lx00st when I do `render js: 'tag_users.js'`, it literally prints to the screen `tag_users.js` on the `save_video` view.

Comment: try also `render 'tag_users.js', content_type: "application/javascript"` in your `save_video` action

Comment: @lx00st Tried that and we are back to the `save_video` view, spitting out the raw escaped HTML, rather than executing it. i.e. the output I specified in Edit 1.

Comment: The really strange thing there is  if that form triggers `save_video` action and it is `:remote => true` than it should send http request as js but it does html

Comment: check your layout for `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`
`<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` and check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227775/rails-form-for-remote-true-is-not-calling-js-method

Comment: @lx00st I just have this in my layout `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` along with `csrt_meta_tags`. Btw, I do have plural `meta_tags` not singular `meta_tag` if that makes a difference. Should I add the `:defaults` symbol to my `js_include_tag`?

Comment: `csrt_meta_tags`  or  `csrf_meta_tags` ?

Comment: Sorry: `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` is what I have. I was fat-fingering it when I typed it. I just tried adding `, :defaults` to the `JS_include_tag` to see what happens. Testing now.

Comment: try with `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` anyway

Comment: and show your application.js

Comment: Tried all of the above and nothing works. Also updated the question with my `application.js`

Comment: Thah show the server log when first `create` is called

Comment: @lx00st Done and posted. Refresh question.

Comment: and the `_upload_video.html.erb` and `upload.js.erb`

Comment: @lx00st - Done. Refresh question.

Comment: Look at the form tag here `<%= form_tag @upload_info[:url], :multipart => true do %>` its not remote. Make it `:remote => true` and show your  server log to `save_video`. Now it should execute rendered js contect.

Comment: @lx00st That doesn't work. But I noticed something else strange, I copied the code from the other JS ERB that works, and it doesn't work once I go to `/tag_users.js`. So it seems it is definitely something local to this method.

Comment: I think something else is broken in my app, because when I try to render anything basic in the `tag_users.js.erb` it doesn't work. Even a basic alert. So there must be something else going weird. I have just simply reverted to `format.html` and putting the content in the partial there. Thanks for all of your hard work @lx00st

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your code

```
 def tag_users
    authorize! :read, @family_tree
    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
    @node = @video.node

    respond_to do |format|
      render format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And, by looking at output i can say that server is receiving `HTML` as format. Since, you want to execute `script` you must send `datatype` to `script`.

Looking at html code, i think you have to pass `data: {type: "script"}` to `simple_form` function, so it will be

```
<div id="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="popup" id="add-video-step-4" data-step="4" data-intro="GETS TO UPLOADING">
  <div class="titles clearfix">
      <h2>Upload a Video</h2>
      <p><i>Step 1 of 3</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <% if @family_tree %>
      <%= simple_form_for([@family_tree, @video], :remote => true,  data: {type: "script"} ) do |f| %>
        <div class="column">
              <div class="f-row">
                  <%= f.input :title, label: "Title:" %>
              </div>
              <div class="f-row">
                  <%= f.input :description,label: "Description:" %>
              </div>
              <div class="f-row">
                  <%= f.input :circa, as: :datepicker, start_year: Date.today.year - 5, label: "Circa:" %>
              </div>
              <div class="f-row">
                  <label for="family">Family in this video:</label>
                  <%= f.collection_select :user_ids, @family_tree.members.order(:first_name), :id, :first_name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
              </div>
          </div>
          <%= f.button :submit, "Add Video", id: "video-submit" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div> <!-- //content -->
</div> <!-- //popup -->
```

See here [Why I need add "data: {type: "script"}" on remote link with rails / ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041506/why-i-need-add-data-type-script-on-remote-link-with-rails-ajax)

Comment: I tried this, but I get the error: `ActionController::UnknownFormat` at the `respond_to do` line in `tag_users`.

Comment: could you please show me the output. Also, i removed the last line of the code from your controller which redirects to some path.

Comment: Now I get a Missing Template Error...specifically: `ActionView::MissingTemplate at /videos/177/save_video
Missing template videos/save_video, application/save_video with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}. `

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the redirect, you might just try adding a format to the redirect path:

```
format.html { redirect_to video_tag_users_path(@video, format: :js) }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either :( It simply outputs the RAW HTML to the screen, and doesn't execute the HTML.